# How to convert frequency into text by using R?

Tags: r, text, frequency, lda

I have dataframe like this (ID, Frequency A B C D E)

```
ID A B C D E    
1  5 3 2 1 0  
2  3 2 2 1 0  
3  4 2 1 1 1
```

I want to convert this dataframe into test based document like this (ID and their frequency ABCDE as words in a single column). Then I may use LDA algorithm to identify hot topics for each ID.

```
ID                     Text
1   "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"
2   "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"
3   "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df1)[,.(list(rep(names(df1)[-1], unlist(.SD)))) ,ID]
DT$V1
#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"

#[[2]]
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"

#[[3]]
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

---

Or a `base R` option is `split`

```
lst <- lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$ID), rep, x=names(df1)[-1])
lst
#$`1`
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"

#$`2`
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"

#$`3`
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

If we want to write the 'lst' to csv file, one option is convert the `list` to `data.frame` by appending `NA` at the end to make the length equal while converting to `data.frame` (as `data.frame` is a `list` with equal length (columns))

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
```

Or use a convenient function from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
res <- stri_list2matrix(lst, byrow=TRUE)
```

and then use the `write.csv`

```
write.csv(res, "yourdata.csv", quote=FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and `rep` like so:

```
apply(df[-1], 1, function(i) rep(names(df)[-1], i))
```

For each row, `apply` feeds the `rep` function the number of times to repeat each variable name. This returns a list of vectors:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Where each list element is a row of your data.frame.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID A B C D E    
1  5 3 2 1 0  
2  3 2 2 1 0  
3  4 2 1 1 1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question: how to write the output to csv. document?

Comment: Lists aren't well designed to write to a csv, since csvs want rectangular data. If you are working in R, you should use `save` and `load`rather than `write.csv` and `read.csv`. If you need to write to csv and since this is out of scope from your first question, I think this would make a great second question to post. Start with the list data that you received from these answers. I looked for a similar question on SO, as I'm sure one exists, but couldn't find it.